# SQL Select the row in Table T1 with lowest row sequence value in other Table T2

Tags: sql

Here is the overview of my tables (Task,TaskSequence, OverallFileProgress and FileProgressStage)

**Task**:

```
TaskId  TaskName
1       File Opened
2       File Assigned
3       File Disposed
```

**TaskSequence**:

```
TaskSequenceId  SequenceNumber  TaskId
1               33              3
2               11              1
3               22              2
```

**OverallFileProgress**:

```
OverallFileProgressId   WorkId
1                       100
2                       101
```

**FileProgressStage**:

```
FileProgressStageId OverallFileProgressId   TaskId  IsCompleted
1                   1                       1       1
2                   1                       2       1
3                   1                       3       0
6                   2                       1       1
7                   2                       2       0
8                   2                       3       0
```

The `FileProgressStage` table is to track the file progress on each stage and mark that stage as complete. This is something like workflow tracking of Office files. Now I want to show that current stage of the WorkId. As per the above data I would like to get the next not completed current stage of the Work like:

```
WorkId  TaskId  TaskName    
100     3       File Disposed   
101     2       File Assigned
```

Here the next stage of task is decided by the `TaskSequence` table order by `SequenceNumber`. So each `WorkId` will flow as per the sequence order defined in the `TaskSequence` table. It means the `WorkId` will flow from FileOpened => FileAssigned => FileDisposed

Comment: So what are you asking?

Comment: And what database engine are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This should work assuming you are using tSQL:

creating data sets:

```
CREATE TABLE #Task
                  (
             TaskId INT, TaskName VARCHAR(50)
                  );

INSERT INTO #Task
VALUES
       (1, 'File Opened'
       ),
       (2, 'File Assigned'
       ),
       (3, 'File Disposed'
       );

CREATE TABLE #TaskSequence
                          (
             TaskSequenceId INT, SequenceNumber INT, TaskId INT
                          );

INSERT INTO #TaskSequence
VALUES
       (1, 33, 3
       ),
       (2, 11, 1
       ),
       (3, 22, 2
       );

CREATE TABLE #OverallFileProgress
                                 (
             OverallFileProgressId INT, WorkId INT
                                 );

INSERT INTO #OverallFileProgress
VALUES
       (1, 100
       ),
       (2, 101
       );

CREATE TABLE #FileProgressStage
                               (
             FileProgressStageId INT, OverallFileProgressId INT, TaskId INT, IsCompleted INT
                               );

INSERT INTO #FileProgressStage
VALUES
       (1, 1, 1, 1
       ),
       (2, 1, 2, 1
       ),
       (3, 1, 3, 0
       ),
       (6, 2, 1, 1
       ),
       (7, 2, 2, 0
       ),
       (8, 2, 3, 0
       );
```

Solution:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT  C.WorkId  , A.TaskId,B.TaskName , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY   C.WorkId   ORDER BY  S.SequenceNumber   ) AS rnk
      FROM #FileProgressStage AS A 
          JOIN #Task AS B ON A.TaskId = B.TaskId 
          JOIN #OverallFileProgress AS C ON A.OverallFileProgressId=C.OverallFileProgressId
        JOIN TaskSequence AS S on B.TaskId=S.TaskId
      WHERE A.IsCompleted <> 1   )

      SELECT cte.WorkId,cte.TaskId,cte.TaskName 
      FROM CTE 
      WHERE rnk = 1
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I do not see the join with TaskSequence where we have defined the sequence number of tasks. The current stage of the Work should be the next TaskId order by SequenceNumber

Comment: can you describe the table #TaskSequence please specifically the field SequenceNumber?

Comment: @Haidar looking at the numerical order of the TaskId and comparing it with the numerical order of the SequenceNumber they are identical.  Is there a particular reason why you want the use the TaskSequence table?

Comment: Yes, the next task id would be determined by the sequence number. You can think about it like we have set of specified tasks. By setting the sequence number, we can order them sequencially. So the next task would be picked by the next Task in sequence order.

Comment: Most of the script fulfill my need. I have made few changes here:
 ;WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT  C.WorkId  , A.TaskId,B.TaskName , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY   C.WorkId   ORDER BY  S.SequenceNumber   ) AS rnk
 FROM #FileProgressStage AS A 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 #Task AS B ON A.TaskId = B.TaskId 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
 #OverallFileProgress AS C ON A.OverallFileProgressId=C.OverallFileProgressId
 JOIN TASKSEQUENCE S on A.TaskId=S.TaskId
 WHERE A.IsCompleted <> 1   )

 SELECT cte.WorkId,cte.TaskId,cte.TaskName 
 FROM CTE 
 WHERE rnk = 1

Comment: @Haidar great I hope I helped somewhat!

Comment: Anyhow, it was a great help Kamran.Thanks!!!